# For each AD-group get member and Operating System in a table

Tags: powershell

Here I am trying to get a list of AD groups and the server in each of these group with the Operating system on a table.

```bsh
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "SUS*"' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $hash = @{GroupName = $_.Name; Member = '' }
        $_ | Get-ADGroupMember -ea 0 -recurs |
        ForEach-Object {
            $hash.Member = $_.Name
            New-Object psObject -Property $hash
        }
    } | sort groupname, member
```

How do I have it so that I have the table in the following format

`GroupName | ServerName | OperatingSystem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to use the `[PSCustomObject]` accelerator than using `New-Object` and a hash like you're doing there.

Also, if you want the OperatingSystem, you need to use `Get-ADComputer`. `Get-ADGroupMember` only returns a `ADPrincipal` object, which cannot contain an OperatingSystem property. Fortunately you can pass that object to `Get-ADComputer`, and that returns a `ADComputer` object, which can contain OperatingSystem if you ask for it.

```bsh
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "SUS*"' | ForEach-Object {
    $groupName = $_.Name
    $_ | Get-ADGroupMember -ea 0 -recurs | Get-ADComputer -Properties OperatingSystem -ea 0 | ForEach-Object {
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            GroupName = $groupName
            ServerName = $_.Name
            OperatingSystem = $_.OperatingSystem
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object GroupName, ServerName
```

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` can also return users or groups. You need to filter for only computer objects before piping to `Get-ADComputer`

Comment: Not when using `-ea 0`, which is the equivalent to `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. I guess using that as the "filter" causes more traffic to the DC, but unless you're doing something crazy, that probably not really an issue.